# How to find which session has occupied your database?

Tags: sql-server, database, session

How to find which session has occupied your database?

Comment: If you meant to [answer the title question yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), you should split off the answer into the appropriate post and reserve the question text for asking the basic question, so others can tell if they have the same problem you did.

Comment: i think these flag will work to help people who  has the same question to find my answer.

Comment: Yes, a [self-answered question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) is designed for that purpose, but it has to be properly formatted to be really useful. This isn't yet: it's too confusing.

Comment: Thanks for you patience to a newbie like me. but i am still confusing about how to format my question? can you help format my self-answered question if you have the permission.

Comment: Well, describe the sort of problem that led to you figuring out how this was done. Put the problem description in the question text, then scroll down to the Answer Your Own Question button, hit that, and put most of what's currently in the question text in the new answer box instead.

Comment: I have found i misunderstand your mean util now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because outdated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Excute below query in SSMS**

```
select 
    b.name,
    a.session_id,
    a.program_name,
    a.login_name,
    a.status
from sys.dm_exec_sessions a 
join sys.databases b 
on a.database_id=b.database_id 
where b.name like '%DatabaseName%'
```

**Then kill it by sesion_id**